# SQL nested/complicated select statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

I to write a script that will update/insert a record about a property. I have determined a method to ensure that the script will not create duplicates but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it.

We take an import from a CSV file that will have a load of properties. This property has a third party reference number from the agent. This can create a duplicate because obviously a separate agent may use the same reference.

In the table it needs to be updated/inserted either buildingNumber, buildingName or AddressLine1 will not be null. Then I need to check the existing records postcode and whichever column isn't null against the column I will be inserting.

I know the table structure is shit. I didn't design it and there's no way I can change it.

I'm looking for something like this.

```
if exists(
  select * from tblMemberProperties
  where ThirdPartyReference = @PropertyThirdPartyReference
  and ((if buildingNumber is not null (then BuildingNumber = @BuildingNumber)
  or (if buildingName is not null and above if isn't satisfied (then buildingName = @BuildingName)
  or (if AddressLine1 is not null and above 2 are null (then AddressLine1 = @AddressLine1))
  and (postcode = @postcode)
```

Comment: It would help enormously if you can show your table structure, sample data, and sample desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if exists(
select * from tblMemberProperties
where Postcode = @Postcode
and BuildingNumber = @BuildingNumber
and BuildingNumber is not null
or 
Postcode = @Postcode
and BuildingName = @BuildingName
and BuildingName is not null
or
Postcode = @Postcode
and AddressLine1 = @AddressLine1
and AddressLine1 is not null)
```